# Adding an image <img src=“?”> dynamically in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I have a book database where i have book information. I have a row where i store the name of the picture of the book i want to display on the page. For example cprog.jpeg

Now, i want to append that name to the src to display the picture. However, its just displaying the name itself. Im not quite sure how to do it.

```
 + " <img src=\"{0} \">" + row[8].ToString() + "</div>"
```

Here is the complete code..

```
foreach (DataTable table in dsgrid2.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    strBooksInCategory +=
                          "<div style=\"height:150px;\">"

                          + " <img src=\"{0} \">" + row[8].ToString() + "</div>"
                        + "  <div style=\"height:110px;float:left;padding-left:10px;\">"
                        + "   <div style=\"height=auto;left-margin:10px;\">" + row[0] + "</div>"
                        + "   <div style=\"height=auto;left-margin:10px;\">" + row[1] + "</div>"
                        + "   <div style=\"height=auto;left-margin:10px;\">" + row[2] + "</div>"
                        + "   <div style=\"height=auto;left-margin:10px;\">" + row[3] + "</div>"
                        + "   <div style=\"height=auto;left-margin:10px;\">" + row[4] + "</div>"
                        + "   <div style=\"height=auto;left-margin:10px;\">" + row[5] + "</div>"
                        + " </div>"
                        + "</div>";
                    strBooksInCategory += "<div style=\"height:10px;width=100%;\"></div>";
```

Comment: There's not a speck of ASP.NET in the posted code. Is that intentional? It smells almost like PHP or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming row[8] is your image name... try something like

```
+ "<img src=\""+ row[8].ToString() +"\"></div>"
```

You will have to put in the path to the image too, that will look like

```
+ "<img src=\"/path/to/image/"+ row[8].ToString() +"\"></div>"
```

However... the other answerer is correct, this is very messy & will only break your heart later. Databound controls are the way to go, read up on DataGrids and Repeaters... it will be worth your while!

Comment: I had a grid and bound to it only to have it changed. This is a school project and 4 of us are working on it.

Comment: both ways didnt display anything

Comment: does it display a broken image?
if so: can you right click & see what image it is trying to display?

Comment: No, it doesnt display anything. its blank like i didnt do anything

Answer (score 1):

You're doing several things horribly wrong:

1. Don't ever concatenate strings like that. Use the `StringBuilder` class instead.
2. Don't even build up HTML by concatenating strings. It produces horribly unmaintainable code. If I saw that in a project I was responsible for, I would tell you to fix it immediately. If I saw it in a project I was not responsible for, I would ask your supervisor to tell you to fix it immediately.
3. Please learn how to use data-bound controls like the `Repeater` control!
4. If the database only contains the name, and if the name is part of the URL, then you need to form the complete URL:

   ```
   String.Format("http://mysite.com/images/{0}.jpg", row[8]);
   ```

Comment: problem is this is a school project where 4 of us are working on it and one guy changed everything around and this is what i have to work with. I personally didnt do it. I am responsible for adding the image.

Comment: In addition to what John said about StringBuilder, it will also help you control/mitigate garbage generation and collection. This list of [StringBuilder methods](http://www.gavpugh.com/2010/04/01/xnac-avoiding-garbage-when-working-with-stringbuilder/) (not complete) will show you which ones create garbage.

Comment: The name of the image is not part of the URL. I have several image names in the database for the different books i have. So, im still unsure how to do this.

Comment: From your code, clearly, `row[8]` is meant to contain either the entire URL, or part of it. You said in your question, "I have a row where i store the name of the picture of the book i want to display on the page. For example cprog.jpeg"

Comment: Actually, a sequence of String concatenations in a single statement is reasonably efficient. The Framework turns those into a single call to String.Concat(), which in turn does a single memory allocation. The grossly inefficient case is when you concatenate from one statement to another, or in a loop. Long single concats are bad form for other reasons, but efficiency isn't the primary. A bigger question for this page is why is there so much markup in the code-behind?

Comment: Since when are those converted to String.Concat?

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid building HTML like that in your code behind. Instead:

1. Move all of the mark-up into an aspx file, and out of the code behind.
2. Switch to using controls instead of bare html: `<asp:Image>` for the `<img>` tag, and `<asp:Panel>` for the `<div>`s
3. Wrap the controls in an `<asp:Repeater>` with an `<ItemTemplate>`
4. Use Data Binding to assign the values from your DataTable to properties of the controls