# Convert text to image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a code of convert text into image using C#. The code is given below.
Now my quetion is that this function return a bitmap image. How to show it in my asp.net page. I want show the image which is returned by this function.

```
private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(string sImageText)
{
    Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);

    int intWidth = 0;
    int intHeight = 0;

    // Create the Font object for the image text drawing.
    Font objFont = new Font("Arial", 20, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // Create a graphics object to measure the text's width and height.
    Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

    // This is where the bitmap size is determined.
    intWidth = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(sImageText, objFont).Width;
    intHeight = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(sImageText, objFont).Height;

    // Create the bmpImage again with the correct size for the text and font.
    objBmpImage = new Bitmap(objBmpImage, new Size(intWidth, intHeight));

    // Add the colors to the new bitmap.
    objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

    // Set Background color
    objGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
    objGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    objGraphics.DrawString(sImageText, objFont, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(102, 102, 102)), 0, 0);
    objGraphics.Flush();
    return (objBmpImage);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

there is an example of this with the following function

```
public Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string txt, string fontname, int fontsize, Color bgcolor, Color fcolor, int width, int Height)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, Height);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {

            Font font = new Font(fontname, fontsize);
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgcolor), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            graphics.DrawString(txt, font, new SolidBrush(fcolor), 0, 0);
            graphics.Flush();
            font.Dispose();
            graphics.Dispose();


        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

and to use this function:

```
ConvertTextToImage(txtvalue.Text, "Bookman Old Style", 10, Color.Yellow, Color.Red, txtvalue.Width, txtvalue.Height);
```

Comment: How to store the return value??

Comment: just give your image the source in the code behind file.

Comment: I have taken image control in asp.nt page

Comment: look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365084/adding-an-image-img-src-dynamically-in-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: `using` syntax calls `Dispose` by itself. `Dispose` is idempotent, though, so there is no error in calling it twice; however, you should remove both calls and wrap the font in `using`.

Comment: this graphics algorithm worked for me, as did the original asker, but this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Create `HttpHandler` (like `image.ashx`) and use something like this code:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        var image = CreateBitmapImage("Hello world");
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

        context.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
    }
```

And where you need to have your image add the link.

```
<img src="image.ashx" alt="image" />
```

**Updated [based on comments]:**

Http handler:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

        var text = context.Request.Params["text"];
        if (text == null) text = string.Empty;
        var image = CreateBitmapImage(text);

        image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

page layout:-

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MyTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="RenderImageButtonClicked" Text="Change text"/>
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="MyTextImage" />
```

page event:-

```
    protected void RenderImageButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTextImage.ImageUrl = "CreateImageText.ashx?text=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(MyTextBox.Text);
    }
```

Comment: how to access the this function CreateBitmapImage() in my .ashx file?
I have written this function in my .aspx.cs page?

Comment: Move your code of CreateBitmapImage method to separated class or into this handler.

Comment: Okey.but then how to pass a value of textbox in this function CreateBitmapImage()
I want CreateBitmapImage(Textbox1.text); instead of
CreateBitmapImage("Hello world");

Comment: Add server image to the page. And during processing the onclick event assign the correct src to this image. See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the image on your page, you need to create an `IMG` tag in HTML. You can do this manually or use the Image-control of ASP.NET. The `IMG` tag contains the address of an image in the src-attribute. This might be a static file reference or - as in your case - the reference to an image that is created dynamically. When the browser displays an HTML file, it looks for `IMG` tags and retrieves the content that is referred to in the src-attribute. 
An easy way to show your dynamically created image, is to create a special page that streams the image to the client. On the page (e.g. in Page_Load), you can use the [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-method of the Bitmap to write it to the response stream:

```
var bm = CreateBitmapImage("MyText");
bm.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

As I read from the comments, the `CreateBitmapImage` method is located in a codebehind page - presumably the page you want to display the image on. In order to call the method when you create the image dynamically, move the code to the new page (you won't need it on the other page anyway).

In your `IMG` tag, link to the newly created page so that the browser will request the image. If you need some data in order to create the image, you need to supply these to the image-page as query parameters, so that in your case the `IMG` tag might look like this:

```
<img src="dynamicimage.aspx?text=Mytext" />
```

Please note that using a handler as @Anton describes is a more elegant approach. But the main building blocks are the same.

Comment: how to access CreateBitmapImage() in Handler.ashx??

Comment: @Sonali: you might need to add a namespace or create an instance of the class that contains the CreateBitmapImage method.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = txtText.Text.Trim();
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
Font font = new Font("Arial", 25, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
int width = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Width;
int height = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Height;
bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, new Size(width, height));
graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.Clear(Color.White);
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)), 0, 0);
graphics.Flush();
graphics.Dispose();
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName()) + ".jpg";
bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
imgText.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + fileName;
imgText.Visible = true;
```